# Typescript/React passing props error 'Does not exist on type...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to get Typescript to work with passing props. Here is my code:

App.tsx

```
export const ProductPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();

  return (
    <UpdateProductPage id={id} /> //throws an error here for id
  )
}
```

UpdateProductPage.tsx

```
interface PropType {
  id: string;
}

export const UpdateProductPage = ({ id }: PropType): JSX.Element => {
  console.log(id)
  //unrelated logic
}
```

so basically in the console I get an error saying the following:

```
Type '{ accessToken: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

I've tried declaring the prop type by doing `UpdateProductPage: React.FC<PropType>` too but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The error message doesn't appear to have anything to do with the code in your question

Comment: No problems here ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bird-9uvp5?file=/src/UpdateProductPage.tsx

Answer (score -2):

Try this way:

UpdateProductPage.tsx

```js
import { FC } from 'react';

interface PropType {
  id: string;
}

export const UpdateProductPage: FC<PropType> = ({ id }): JSX.Element => {
  console.log(id)
}
```

Or change interface to use type.

```js
type PropType = {
  id: string;
}
```

To complement: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/